# A way to select maximal values from an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

This will return the first instance of the longest string in an array:

```
["abcd","efgh","ijk"].max_by { |x| x.length } # => "abcd"
```

Similarly to this, is there a nice way to get an array of all strings with the maximal length?

```
["abcd","efgh","ijk"].some_trick ... # => ["abcd","efgh"]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here we go :

```
["abcd","efgh","ijk"].group_by(&:size).max.last #=> ["abcd","efgh"]
```

Explanation :

- [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) gives a hash containing each unique size of strings contained in the array as keys, and the matching strings as values => `{4=>["abcd", "efgh"], 3=>["ijk"]}`
- [Enumerable#max](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) applied on a Hash will give us the highest key with its matching values, in an Array like this : `[key, values]` => `[4, ["abcd", "efgh"]]`
- [Array#last](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-last) will give us the last element of the array ... => `["abcd", "efgh"]`

Comment: I dunno, looking each of those methods up in the doc seems like it'd tell you plenty. Or doing `["abcd","efgh","ijk"].group_by(&:size)` then `_.max` then `_.last` in irb.